# checking,if a string of an array of strings is available in a string

Tags: php

all string functions(preg_match,strpos...) in php I know allow me to find a string in a string. My intention is to find a string of an array of strings in a string like this:

```
         $pattern = array("jpg", "bmp");
         $subject = $bild->dateiname;
```

Any ideas,how to implemnet my intention using php-function(s)?

Comment: Did you look at the manual? The answer is in there. Same for using Google.

Comment: Do you need to know which one is found or if ANY are found?

Comment: ... or if ALL are found?

Comment: `if(preg_match('/\.('.implode('|'.$patern).')/', $subject)) echo 'yes';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the string in an array

```
<pre>
<?php       

  $pattern = array("jpg", "bmp");

  $yourString ="bmp dd ddd ddd";
  $string = (explode(" ",$yourString));


    echo findeStirng($pattern,$string);

    function findeStirng($pattern,$string){
         foreach ($string as $val){
             foreach ($pattern as $valpat){
             $find="";
             if ($val==$valpat){
                 $find ="finde string";
                 return $find;
                 break;
             }
             }
             }
         }
?>

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see if any one of the array strings is in the subject string, then attempt to replace them and check if there was a replacement:

```
if(str_replace($pattern, '', $subject) != $subject) {
    echo 'something was found';
}
```

Or:

```
if(str_replace($pattern, '', $subject, $count) && $count) {
    echo 'something was found';
}
```

To capture the match use `preg_match` or to capture all matches:

```
preg_match_all('/(' . implode('|', $pattern) . ')/', $subject, $matches);
```

Then inspect `$matches`.